# Diificulty in reading dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file as follows:

```
[8:3:1978] LOG [Sale:internals.py:makeSaleEntry:0] Entered with productid= 2327, storeid= 146, No.OfUnits= 1
[19:1:2007] LOG [Sale:internals.py:makeSaleEntry:1] Entered with productid= 1908, storeid= 202, No.OfUnits= 11
[22:4:2001] LOG [Sale:internals.py:makeSaleEntry:2] Entered with productid= 3072, storeid= 185, No.OfUnits= 16
[22:12:1915] LOG [Sale:internals.py:makeSaleEntry:3] Entered with productid= 1355, storeid= 177, No.OfUnits= 1
[19:8:1963] LOG [Sale:internals.py:makeSaleEntry:4] Entered with productid= 2235, storeid= 35, No.OfUnits= 16
[16:11:1997] LOG [Sale:internals.py:makeSaleEntry:5] Entered with productid= 1439, storeid= 141, No.OfUnits= 26
```

and I have read the file using a dataframe df.

```
df = pd.read_csv('a.txt')
```

I want to access the dataframe line-by-line and print in another csv file the productid, storeid and No.OfUnits as follows:

```
2327,146,1
1908,202,11
3072,185,16
1355,177,1
2235,35,16
1439,141,26
```

My piece of code is:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    strr = ""
    for j, column in row.iteritems():
        seq = column.split('= ')
        strr = strr + seq[1] + ","
    file = open("a.csv", "a")
    file.write(strr[:-1]+"\n")
    file.close()
```

This code is working fine except it ignores writing the first line (2327,146,1). Please suggest changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem when read the file using tuples.

```
lines = tuple(open('a.txt', 'r'))
for line in lines:
    file = open("a.csv", "a")
    strr = line.split()
    file.write(strr[len(strr)-5] + strr[len(strr)-3] + strr[len(strr)-1] + "\n")
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add header=None parameter.

`df = pd.read_csv('a.txt', header=None)`

Answer (score 1):

Your code ignored the first line because by default `read_csv` assumes it is a header. You can make your original code work by adding `header=None` as suggested above. You might also want to consider a more readable version using regular expressions to extract the values.

```
df = pd.read_csv('a.txt', header=None)
df['productid'] = df[0].str.findall('productid= ([0-9]+)').apply(lambda l: l[0])
df['storeid'] = df[1].str.findall('storeid= ([0-9]+)').apply(lambda l: l[0])
df['No.OfUnits'] = df[2].str.findall('No.OfUnits= ([0-9]+)').apply(lambda l: l[0])
df1 = df.loc[:, ['productid', 'storeid', 'No.OfUnits']]
df1.to_csv('a.csv', header=False, index=False, mode='a')
```

BTW pandas is not really necessary for this. This will also work:

```
import re
with open('a.txt') as f:
    values = [re.findall('productid= ([0-9]+), storeid= ([0-9]+), No.OfUnits= ([0-9]+)', 
                        line)[0] for line in f]
with open('a.csv', 'a') as f:
    for v in values:
        f.write(','.join(v) + '\n')
```